# How to run standalone Expo React Native project on a real device and still be able to see console logs?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, expo

Before you tell me to use the expo app... I must deploy using a standalone app because Im implementing faceID and as you know the expo app does not support faceID. I want to be able to run the app on my actual device using a standalone so the faceID works, but I also need to see the console logs I have put into place in my react native code... I know when you bare react native you simply open the .xcworkspace from your projects iOS folder and run it inside Xcode and use it to run the app on your iPhone and still see your debug info in the debug window of Xcode, but I need the Expo equivalent of this.

Comment: see this page for more info https://docs.expo.io/workflow/logging/#optional-manually-access-device-logs

Comment: Its not the greatest debugger because you are bombarded with all logs from your device and not just the app I believe but I actually was able to use command F and search for what I was looking for, thank you so much.